# Panic mode after upgrading to ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, kernel

I have an XPS 13 Dell laptop with Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10. After the upgrade there were some errors. i reboot and there was kernel panic mode. I downloaded again 14.04 i made my bootable but it seems i can't even install Ubuntu 14.04. When rebooting there is black screen with:

```
Minimal  Bash-like line editing is supported. For the first word. TAB lists possible command completions.Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file competions.
grub> _
```

What has happened? How i restore my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck at a grub prompt, that means that you aren't even booting into Linux. You will either need to reinstall from media, or do some serious technical gymnastics to recover the system.

Having said that, it doesn't mean that your data is lost. During an install, you can attempt to not make the file systems, which is dangerous. Also, you could boot with a live distribution (like the Ubuntu installer) and use that interface to mount your disk and backup to other media. There is no one prescribed way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I occassionally get the same error but have a simple remedu reboot. Why it works, I have no idea but when I do reboot, I get the GRUB menu.

The first time it happened I went through troubleshooting but found no errors, the next time it occurred I simply chose the top option, forget what it was and was able to get in.

It occurred for a 3rd time, but this time I simply rebooted, chose the first option on the GRUB screen and was able to get in.